# Char or Int for boolean value in C?

Tags: c

I find that there is no native `bool` type. People either use `int` or `char` - though it seem that `int` might be more frequently used than `char`? Is this true?

My first impulse was to use `char` as it is a smaller data type, but there something I've missed? Is `int` better for boolean values, and if so - why?

Comment: maybe because 0 is false with an int? more intuitive!

Comment: int tends to be used as it is untuitive, char is used for optimal data size.

Comment: @Ali A `char` would get promoted to an `int` in a `if` statement anyway. It's just a matter of space optimization: `char`s are generally smaller than `int`s.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There is a `_Bool` in [C99](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C99), and a `bool` if you include [`stdbool.h`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stdbool.h#stdbool.h).

If you don't have it (a decently modern compiler), use `int`, it's usually the fastest type. The memory savings of using `char` are likely negligible.

Comment: So why is `char` faster than `int`? I mean, a larger datatype is faster to process?

Comment: @thomthom What I actually said is that `int` is faster. It's the fastest because it has the CPUs natural word size. It's what CPUs crave. See [this awesome answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5069643/226266).

Comment: I'd seen the `bool` in C99 - I was just wondering of the use of `char` vs `int` if you didn't. Just to understand more of how it's all working. But if we include `bool` in this, how is it in performance with `int`? Is it a cloaked int, or a genuine new datatype?

Comment: @thomthom The standard is (as it should be) quite generic. *An object declared as type _Bool is large enough to store the values 0 and 1*.

Comment: That was a typo on my part - I mean "`int` faster than `char` - I just got some wires crossed. That linked answer was mighty interesting and informing.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using a reasonably modern C compiler then you just need:

```
#include <stdbool.h>
```

This typically has a macro such as:

```
#define bool _Bool
```

which lets you use C99's built-in `_Bool` type wherever you need a `bool`.

Answer (score 2):

There is a native type named `_Bool` (starting with C99). In `<stdbool.h>`, there's also a `#define` to provide `bool` as an alias, if you want it (also has `#define`s for `true` and `false`).

Answer (score 1):

Actually there's no real difference since char gets always promoted to int when using it (check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3900385/data-type-promotions-during-arithmetic-operations)). I have never seen a char used as a bool though, so I'd go for using an int.

Comment: So that is why `int` is faster? Because `char` is turned into an `int`?

Comment: @thomthom: Yes, that's why. But the speed gain is so small that you can forget it :)

Answer (score 1):

According to *ISO-9899* the result of relation, logical and equality operators has type `int`. `true` and `false` from `stdbool.h` are also integers. If you want to spare memory - use bit-fields.