# What problems can one face on dividing a long long by int?

Tags: c++, c

What is a safer method to perform division:

`long long / int` or `long long / (long long) int`?

On dividing a long long by an int, can there be some security issues or any logical issues?

Comment: Such operations should be implemented always using the biggest type. But I do not have references to support this.

Comment: As long as you don't divide by zero, anyone is safe, except that if the denominator i larger than the numerator you will get a `0`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3900417/2651076

Comment: arithmetic operations on integers of the same signedness work as expected. The smaller type (if any) is correctly promoted to the larger type.

Comment: @iharob MinValue / -1 is certainly not safe.

Answer (score 4):

> On dividing a long long by an int, can there be some security issues
>   or any logical issues?

The answer is **NO** with a condition that your denominator is not 0.

From the docs:

> Many binary operators that expect operands of arithmetic or enumeration type cause conversions and yield result types in a similar way. The purpose is to yield a common type, which is also the type of the result. This pattern is called the *usual arithmetic conversions*, which are defined as follows:
>
> - If either operand is of type `long double`, the other shall be converted to `long double`.
> - Otherwise, if either operand is `double`, the other shall be converted to `double`.
> - Otherwise, if either operand is `float`, the other shall be converted to `float`.
> - Otherwise, the integral promotions (4.5) shall be performed on both operands.
> - Then, if either operand is `unsigned long` the other shall be converted to `unsigned long`.
> - Otherwise, if one operand is a `long int` and the other `unsigned int`, then if a `long int` can represent all the values of an `unsigned int`, the `unsigned int` shall be converted to a `long int`; otherwise both operands shall be converted to `unsigned long int`.
> - Otherwise, if either operand is `long`, the other shall be converted to `long`.
> - Otherwise, if either operand is `unsigned`, the other shall be converted to `unsigned`.
>
> [*Note:* otherwise, the only remaining case is that both operands are `int`]

So it would be like

```
int / int => returns int

float / float => returns float

double /double => returns double

int / double => returns double

int / float => returns float
```

Comment: `long.MinValue (as if I remembered the macro) / -1 = ?` :-)

Comment: LLONG_MIN / -1 gives Floating Point Exception. Although, LLONG_MIN / (long long) (-1) also gives Floating Point Exception. Why is that?

Comment: Because it overflows, and (signed) integer overflow has undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

As has already been said, going up the scale from lower to higher precision (e.g. float to double to long double, there is no problem with conversions) —each higher one in the list can hold all the values of the lower ones, so the conversion occurs with no loss of information.

For integral promotions (e.g long int and int)

If either operand is a long int, then the other one is converted to long int, and that is the type of the result.

So, this is safe (except divide by zero, of course). For more [details](http://publications.gbdirect.co.uk/c_book/chapter2/expressions_and_arithmetic.html).